# Spring Boot custom logback logger to file only

Tags: spring-boot, logback, fileappender

I've got a pair of custom loggers defined for LogBack in a Spring Boot application.  The idea is to send all of that logging to a file, instead of the standard console output provided by Spring Boot by default.  What I'm seeing is that the logging goes to both the custom file AND the console, and I cannot find any reason for that to happen.  All logging to the two custom appenders is at DEBUG and/or TRACE level.  I have set logging.level.root=INFO, thinking that would prevent this logging from showing up, but that didn't help.

I do have the standard Spring Boot logging configured for use in the application.  So logging.path and logging.file are both set.

Any help appreciated.

Here is my custom logback-spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    LogBack configuration used by all services to create separate files for TRACE and SOAP logs. 
-->
<configuration>
    <!-- Include the basic Spring-Boot logback configuration. -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <!-- An appender and logger for TRACE logging of method calls -->
    <appender name="TraceLoggingAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/logs/trace.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="TraceLogging" additivity="false" level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="TraceLoggingAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- An appender and logger for SOAP envelope logging -->
    <appender name="SoapLoggingAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/logs/soap.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="SoapLogging" additivity="false" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="SoapLoggingAppender"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

And an example usage:

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog("SoapLogging");
...
LOG.debug(soapMessage);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable console logging and write output only to a file, you need a custom logback-spring.xml that imports file-appender.xml but not console-appender.xml, as shown in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You also need to add logging.file.name to your application.properties, as shown in the following example:

```
logging.file.name=myapplication.log
```

Courtesy: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including `base.xml` include `defaults.xml` as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly)

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
```

Comment: That did not help me.  I'm still seeing logging from the SoapLogging appender on the CONSOLE.  I only want those statements to go to the defined file.

Comment: Sorry, but that did not work, either.  The net effect was to shut down logging entirely, or, at least, sent the files somewhere that I can't find them.